# Matrix + combinatorial or conditional probability: bit patterns

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, binary

I'm trying to get my head around a problem, and it's not working.

The problem: consider an NxN matrix that represents a binary number. For instance, a 4x4 matrix is a 16 bit number, a 6x6 matrix is a 36 bit number. N will always be even.

Now, for any given N, how many matrices / numbers are there where every row and column has exactly half of its values 0 and half 1?

Here is what I have learned so far:

- From brute force, I know that the answer for a 2x2 matrix is 2. For a 4x4 matrix, the answer is 90.
- I can calculate the number of rows OR columns that half half of their bits on with the formula:
  $$
  f(n) = {n! \over (n/2)!^2} * 2 ^ {n^2}
  $$
- But I can't simply take percentage of rows times percentage of columns, presumably because they are not independent.

This started out of curiosity and has become an obsession. Please help.

Comment: nice question! +1

Answer (score 3):

This sequence appears in [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A058527), wherein there are references such as [this](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v12i1r29) article in the Electronic Journal of Combinatorics, which gives asymptotic results.

The sequence, incidentally, begins $1, 2, 90, 297200, 116963796250, 6736218287430460752,\ldots$

Comment: Thanks for that -- it is indeed the correct sequence. And the article is interesting. So far, it looks like there is no general solution, which is pretty frustrating. But thanks for the additional info!